# Strategy to design specification table for measurements data for analytical database project

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I need advice on the following topic:

I am developing a DW/BI solution in SQL Server and reports are published in Power BI.

Main part of my question starts here: I have a large table which collects measurement data on product measurement for multiple attributes. Product can be of multiple type, that can be recognised by item number in this table, measurements can be done multiple times and can be identified by measurement date. Usually, we refer latest dates. If it makes things complicated, I can filter data for latest dates only. This is dense row table (multi million). Number of attribute counts about 200.

I want to include specifications for these attributes most likely in a dimension table, and there may be tens of such specifications. Intention is that user shall select in the report any one specification name and he would like to see each product with attributes passing/failing as well as the products passing if all all of specification attributes are passed.

I currently have this measurement table and a dim table with test names, I can add a table for specification if needed. Specification can define few or all test names with lower/upper spec limits:

Sample measurement table:

[image]

Sample dim table for test names:

[image]

I can add a table for specification as below and user will select any of one:

[image]

e.g. Use select ID_spec = 1 then measurement table may look like:

[image]

Some spec may contain all and some few attributes.

Please suggest strategy to design a spec table to be efficient for such large size tables. Please let me know if any further details needed.

Later, I will have to further work to calculate % of pass product if they have been tested for all needed tests in a specification selected.

Comment: Is `Product` an individual unit, or a type of unit?  Is a `Test` performed on the same `Product` more than one?

Comment: @bbaird, I just edited my question. Kindly check.

Comment: multi million row fact tables are small.....

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large tables, the best thing to do is choose the right key.  That means dumping the "Id" column (nothing more than a row identifier) and replacing it with something that:

- Guarantees uniqueness
- Facilitates searches

That often means composite keys, which are fine.

It's also means dumping the whole "fact/dimension" mindset and just focusing on the relations.  This is also fine.

Based on your description, this is the first draft of a data model for your warehouse.  If you are unfamiliar with IDEF1X diagrams, please [read this](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf).

[image]

I've added a unique constraint to `SpecCd` so you could specify the value directly instead of having to check both the `ProductId` and `SpecCd` to return a result.

`ProductTest` exists so you can provide integrity for `ProductTestCriteria` and ensure tests are limited to only those products that can be measured by them.  If all products are subject to all tests, this can be removed and `Test` can relate directly to `ProductMeasurement` and `ProductTestCriteria`.

If you want to subject the latest test of "Product A" to "Spec S" your query would look like:

```
SELECT
  Measurement.ProductId
 ,Measurement.TestCd
 ,Measurement.TestDt
 ,Criteria.SpecCd
 ,Measurement.Value
 ,CASE
    WHEN Measurement.Value BETWEEN Criteria.LowerValue AND Criteria.UpperValue THEN 'Pass'
    ELSE 'Fail'
  END AS Result
FROM
  ProductMeasurement Measurement
INNER JOIN
  ProductTestCriteria Criteria
    ON Critera.ProductId = Measurement.ProductId
         AND Criteria.TestCd = Measurement.TestCd
WHERE
  Measurement.ProductId = 'A'
    AND Criteria.SpecCd = 'S'
    AND Measurement.TestDt =
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(TestDt)
        FROM
          ProductMeasurement
        WHERE
          ProductId = Measurement.ProductId
      )
```

You could remove the filters for `ProductId` and `SpecCd` and roll that into a view - users could later specify for the Products and specifications they want later.

If you want result as of a given date, the query is easily modified to this or incorporated into a TVF:

```
SELECT
  Measurement.ProductId
 ,Measurement.TestCd
 ,Measurement.TestDt
 ,Criteria.SpecCd
 ,Measurement.Value
 ,CASE
    WHEN Measurement.Value BETWEEN Criteria.LowerValue AND Criteria.UpperValue THEN 'Pass'
    ELSE 'Fail'
  END AS Result
FROM
  ProductMeasurement Measurement
INNER JOIN
  ProductTestCriteria Criteria
    ON Critera.ProductId = Measurement.ProductId
         AND Criteria.TestCd = Measurement.TestCd
WHERE
  Measurement.ProductId = 'A'
    AND Criteria.SpecCd = 'S'
    AND Measurement.TestDt =
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(TestDt)
        FROM
          ProductMeasurement
        WHERE
          ProductId = Measurement.ProductId
            AND TestDt <= <Your Date>
      )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such  a detailed explanation. I have started learning Kimball methodology since last few years. Your inputs are somewhat high level for me and will take time to digest. Still, I think it shows me a direction, will come back if I have questions in implementation. I will mark as an answer, but still welcome others to still respond if they have more inputs to it or have further explanations. IDEF1X diagrams is new for me, would go through it.

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask as you go along.

Comment: Have been working on this, few small clarifications before going ahead. Here **ProductId** - is each product Number or ID for Product type? **Cd** suffix means candidate key? What is the difference of tables shown with **dotted links**? In the table, **Product specification**, you use ProductId and SpecCd perhaps together as unique key, kindly confirm?  I now somewhat can understand AK, candidate key etc, but still can't relate much use compare to Primary key/ Foreign/Surrogate key. Sorry for many questions, but I want to gain from this new knowledge as much possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `ProductId` is your specification - I don't know the context within your problem but if you can provide more detail. 2. `Cd` = Code, just some shorthand definition you'll need to determine (or may already exist in some business context).   3. You are correct.  It is a composite so that a given specification can only belong to one `Product` and only include information for `Test` valid for that `Product`. 4. Alternate keys are required when using surrogate keys and for other requirements - they provide uniqueness.

Comment: Expanding on 4: Let's say `Test` has an accepted shorthand/code that is accepted by those familiar with them ('T202B','W391',etc,).  These provide uniqueness and are a good selection for a primary key.  However, they are a substitution for the `Name` of the test, we still need to ensure the `Name` is unique, hence the alternate key.

Comment: Some of the other items are address in the PDF I linked to in the answer, but dotted lines refer to relations that are non-identifying - the primary key of the parent entity does not form the primary key of the child entity.  Which leads me to: there is an error in the diagram, a identifying relationship exists between `Product` and `ProductSpecification` but is not shown on the diagram.